# JavaScript document object lastModified using toLocale string

Tags: javascript

I have to write a piece of Javascript that prints when the file was last modified and I wrote it this way

```html
 <script>
                function myFunction() {
                var x = document.lastModified;
                document.getElementById("last_modified").innerHTML = x;
              }
            </script>
            <script>
                myFunction()
            </script>
```

Actually this works fine but my requirement is to write it this way but using toLocaleString() method as well, I googled it and found this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035009/how-to-see-the-last-modified-html-date-by-javascript) but I couldn't make it work so I hope you could help me 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to get the basic date in English, without other locales:

```
var d = new Date(document.lastModified);
document.getElementById("last_modified").innerHTML = d.toLocaleString();
```